# W3C RSS Validator: Invalid URL

Tags: rss, w3c-validation, rss-reader, rss2, rfc3986

Validation Page
[image]

RSS Item

[image]

I am trying to Validate my RSS Feed using https://validator.w3.org/
I am getting error

```
This feed does not validate.
line 2, column 3719: url must be a full URL: http://www.uktech.news/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/shutterstock_731742925.jpg
```

This URL is Valid and is According to RFC 3986.
I cannot figure out what is wrong with this URL. 
If I remove ".news" from this URL my RSS is validated.
What is wrong with ".news" domain? It is Valid TLD Label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [W3C validator says 'feed does not validate' 'url must be a full URL'... whats wrong with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985571/w3c-validator-says-feed-does-not-validate-url-must-be-a-full-url-whats-wr)

Comment: @unor Its not a Duplicate of Question you Mentioned.

Comment: So, you tried to provide a HTTPS URL and the error stays the same? Please include in your question a minimal code example that gives this error.